# Display a line with a dot before and after

Tags: css

I want to display something like this image :

[image]

I am struggling with the :before and :after, I can't manage to display a perfectly aligned line with the dots.

```css
.line {
  height: 3px;
  width: 50px;
  background: green;
}

.line::before {
  content: "\A";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: green;
}

.line::after {
  content: "\A";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
```

;
margin-bottom: 8px;

```
      &:before, &:after {
        @extend .dot;
      }
    }

  .dot {
    content: "\A";
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```css
.line {
  height: 3px;
  width: 50px;
  background: green;
  position: relative; 
}

.line:after, 
.line:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute; 
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: green; 
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 50%
}

.line:after {
  right: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) in this case. [`justify-content: space-between`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#justify-content) will align them horizontally and [`align-items: center`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#justify-content) would align them vertically.

```css
.line {
  height: 3px;
  width: 50px;
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.line::before {
  content: "\A";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: green;
}

.line::after {
  content: "\A";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
```